# Transform horizontal to vertical data in google sheets

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-bigquery, etl

We have thousands of rows in a google sheet that need to be transformed and loaded into a database.  The layout of the data is unsuitable for our database schema so the data need to be transformed before they are loaded into the database.

How can horizontal data be programatically transformed to vertical data?

Sample sheet is available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QUGuUuBqGpcGUSQHtRlvaMBMls-AVKYkArEuV2Mz3Ok/edit?usp=sharing).

Source data (horizontal layout):

```
Company name    2017-01-14  2017-02-14  2017-03-14
Company 1       1522        1141        1505
Company 2       1866        1909        1610
Company 3       1726        1237        1057
Company 4       1427        1375        1446
Company 5       1590        1819        1352
```

Required result (Vertical layout):

```
2017-01-14  Company 1   1522
2017-01-14  Company 2   1866
2017-01-14  Company 3   1726
2017-01-14  Company 4   1427
2017-01-14  Company 5   1590
2017-02-14  Company 1   1141
2017-02-14  Company 2   1909
2017-02-14  Company 3   1237
2017-02-14  Company 4   1375
2017-02-14  Company 5   1819
2017-03-14  Company 1   1505
2017-03-14  Company 2   1610
2017-03-14  Company 3   1057
2017-03-14  Company 4   1446
2017-03-14  Company 5   1352
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query uses the header argument to create a single row for all rows with data (one row per cell/header). JOIN is then used to suck everything into one cell. Then all the data is placed into its own cell using SPLIT. The TRANSPOSE function creates one vertical column per range from this data.

Comment: It works! (I've locked the sheet to preserve the answer.)

Comment: His query is as follows: =
ArrayFormula(substitute(split(transpose(split(join( " ", query(to_text(C1)&"_"&substitute(B2:B6, " ", "~")&"_"&C2:E6,,50000)), " ")), "_"), "~", " "))

Comment: I ran into a problem applying this to the entire dataset.  google appears to have a limit of 50k characters so I had to join 20 rows at a time - example as follows: =QUERY({ArrayFormula(substitute(split(transpose(split(join( " ", query(to_text(input!C1:AH1)&"_"&substitute(input!A2:A20, " ", "~")&"_"&input!C2:AH20,,50000)), " ")), "_"), "~", " ")); ArrayFormula(substitute(split(transpose(split(join( " ", query(to_text(input!C1:AH1)&"_"&substitute(input!A21:A40, " ", "~")&"_"&input!C21:AH40,,50000)), " ")), "_"), "~", " "))},"Select * where Col1 is not null",1)

Answer (score 1):

> thousands of rows ... need to be transformed and loaded into a database

Based on tag for this question, I assume database is BigQuery

I can suggest loading data as is to BigQuery or create external table - after which you can use below query to do transformation you need

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ['2017-01-14', '2017-02-14', '2017-03-14'][OFFSET(pos)] day, 
  company_name, 
  value
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST([date_20170114, date_20170214, date_20170314]) value WITH OFFSET pos
-- ORDER BY day, company_name
```

You can test / play with it using dumy data from your question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Company 1' company_name, 1522 date_20170114, 1141 date_20170214, 1505 date_20170314 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Company 2', 1866, 1909, 1610 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Company 3', 1726, 1237, 1057 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Company 4', 1427, 1375, 1446 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Company 5', 1590, 1819, 1352 
)
SELECT 
  ['2017-01-14', '2017-02-14', '2017-03-14'][OFFSET(pos)] day, 
  company_name, 
  value
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST([date_20170114, date_20170214, date_20170314]) value WITH OFFSET pos
ORDER BY day, company_name
```

Comment: We are trying to stick with google sheets for the transform as our SQL skills are limited.  We use data studio to import our data and produce dashboards - it works surprisingly well.  We use big query selectively when we hit scale limits in sheets (to simply create views that UNION ALL and/or JOIN lots of sheets).

Comment: sure. makes sense